# Workaround for C# ListView control's CheckedItems.Count Method taking too long to return

Tags: c#, listview, delay, checkeditems

I've got a `ListView` control that has over a million `ListViewItems`.  Each `ListViewItems` contains *two* strings.  I'm pulling all the registry entries for a *Windows* machine -- both the **path + key name**, and the data.

When I attempt to call `ListView.CheckedItems.Count`, it won't return as fast as I'm expecting it to (I've tested running it for days waiting for it to respond). At first I thought I was hitting some type of lock contention issue, however, when I lowered the number of entries in the control, the method would return. What's odd is that the time it takes to traverse the list seems to double for every **100,000** entries:

- **100,000** takes **00:45** to return.
- **200,000** takes **03:58** to return.
- **300,000** takes **09:31** to return.
- **400,000** takes **17:08** to return.
- **500,000** takes **26:56** to return.

Traversing through the items to see if it is "checked" or not shouldn't take this long, even with **500,000** entries, right?  What could be going on and is there a workaround?

System info:

> Windows 10 Enterprise 64-bit (Fully patched as of 9/11/2017) 32GB of
>   Ram Visual Studio 2017 .NET Framework 4.6.1

The amount of ram used while running hovers around **5GB**.  CPU utilization is negligible -- looking at this program in *Sysinternals ProcessExplorer* shows that a single thread is running at around **12%** while it calculates the value of the checked items count.

The application is a simple *windows form*.  The delay happens if stepping through in *debugger* mode or if directly running the release built binary.